# aws s3 sdk php Encountered a permanent redirect while getObjects

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

i'm new to AWS s3, trying to figure out how to use it in php. 
i started using and i can list all my buckets using s3->listBuckets method, yet when i try to list all objects inside this bucket it fail with

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: Encountered a permanent
>   redirect while requesting
>   https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ischool.simplein?encoding-type=url.
>   Are you sure you are using the correct region for this bucket? in
>   /Users/momen/Desktop/studio/s3/sdk/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/PermanentRedirectMiddleware.php:49
>   Stack trace:

point is, the credentials i have are for us-west-2 account, yet when i created s3 bucket i chose to host it in eu-london.

sample code to replicate problem.

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
// Use the us-west-2 region and latest version of each client.

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET
    ]
]);


$buckets = $s3->listBuckets(); // works
$bucket = $buckets['Buckets'][1]['Name'];

$objects = $s3->listObjects([ 'Bucket' => $bucket ]) // FAIL with permenant redirect
```

so which region should i use ? and how come i can list buckets, but not be able to utlize them ?

Comment: Here is the right link which works: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ischool.simplein?encoding-type=url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to the first question:

> Which region should i use?

You should use the region `eu-west-2`

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) is the link to the documentation for all the regions.

Now to the other question:

> How to utilize buckets?

This error looks strongly that you have the false region. So I would consider changing the region and then try it again.

Here is a other related question: [Amazon S3 Upload error PermanentRedirectException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573437/amazon-s3-upload-error-permanentredirectexception)